# Tensorflow.JS WASM, number of cores

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, webassembly

I am trying to run tensorflow.js in node.js but with `wasm` backend.

Works well except setting number of cores used, it is always 1, no matter of fact that I am setting it to 4 and before choosing backend as it should be according to docs.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const tfwasm = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm');

async function run() {
    tfwasm.setThreadsCount(4);

    await tf.setBackend('wasm');
    console.log(tf.getBackend(), tfwasm.getThreadsCount()); // displays: "wasm 1" but should display: "wasm 4"

    //

    const img = tf.ones([1, 224, 224, 3]).toFloat();

    //

    const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
        'https://tfhub.dev/google/tfjs-model/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_130_224/classification/3/default/1',
        { fromTFHub: true }
    );

    //

    const prediction = await model.predict(img);
    
    console.log(prediction);
}
 
run();
```

The same problem is on Windows and same problem on Linux (WSL 2 Ubuntu 22).
Node.js is v18.15.0